# Sorting of Gridview data

Tags: c#, gridview

I have A Grid view and I want to sort the Gridview .I tried severel methods from google and they are not working in my side.

my gridvie code is like

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridviewShopData" runat="server" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Width="100%"
                        AllowSorting="True"  AutoGenerateColumns="False" GridLines="None"
                        CssClass="contactList grid"  PageSize="30" ShowHeaderWhenEmpty="true">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fornavn">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Fornavn") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Efternavn">
            <ItemTemplate>
                   <%# Eval("Efternavn") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Medarbejder nummer">
            <ItemTemplate>
                   <%# Eval("Medarbejder nummer") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
         <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Varenummer">
            <ItemTemplate>
                   <%# Eval("Varenummer") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <AlternatingRowStyle CssClass="altrow" />
                        <PagerSettings FirstPageText="First" LastPageText="Last" PageButtonCount="50" />
                        <EmptyDataTemplate>
                            There is no data available to display!
                        </EmptyDataTemplate>
    <PagerStyle CssClass="pager" />
  </asp:GridView>
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" SelectCommand="SELECT firstName as 'Fornavn',lastName as 'Efternavn',employeeNumber as 'Medarbejder nummer',productID as 'Varenummer' FROM sydShopOrder where shopID=@pageid">
    <SelectParameters><asp:QueryStringParameter Name="pageid" QueryStringField="id"/></SelectParameters>

</asp:SqlDataSource>
```

how to make it possible anyone help.

Comment: you need to set the SortExpression property of the TemplateField..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set `SortExpression` in template field and try

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Fornavn" SortExpression="Fornavn">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <%# Eval("Fornavn") %>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

do this for all that columns which you want to sort

Comment: why was it not working earlier?what change have you made?And my name is Anuj not Anju